# MySQL: handling conditional values within GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying retrieve data using a LEFT JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT(). However, where values aren't present, I need something to represent the lack of data, or a method of identification for each, so that I can do something with them in the application.

```
CONCAT_WS(0x1D,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod1.value
            SEPARATOR 0x1F),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod2.value
            SEPARATOR 0x1F),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod3.value
            SEPARATOR 0x1F),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod4.value
            SEPARATOR 0x1F)) AS clients_options
```

Here, the four instances of GROUP_CONCAT() relate to either an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN in a search performed by the user:

```
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options bco1 ON (bco1.client_id = '3')
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options_data bcod1 ON (bco1.name = 'unit_code')
    AND (bco1.bookings_client_option_id = bcod1.bookings_client_option_id)
    AND (bcod1.value REGEXP ('.*'))
    AND (bcod1.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id)
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options bco2 ON (bco2.client_id = '3')
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options_data bcod2 ON (bco2.name = 'creditor_ev_number')
    AND (bco2.bookings_client_option_id = bcod2.bookings_client_option_id)
    AND (bcod2.value REGEXP ('.*'))
    AND (bcod2.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id)
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options bco3 ON (bco3.client_id = '3')
    LEFT JOIN
bookings_clients_options_data bcod3 ON (bco3.name = 'purchase_order_number')
    AND (bco3.bookings_client_option_id = bcod3.bookings_client_option_id)
    AND (bcod3.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id)
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options bco4 ON (bco4.client_id = '3')
    INNER JOIN
bookings_clients_options_data bcod4 ON (bco4.name = 'purchase_order_booking')
    AND (bco4.bookings_client_option_id = bcod4.bookings_client_option_id)
    AND (bcod4.value REGEXP ('Y'))
    AND (bcod4.booking_attendee_id = bookings_attendees.booking_attendee_id)
```

Here, bcod3.value is where the results "collapse" in that if there's no value for bcod3.value but a value for bcod4.value, then bcod4.value drops into the space for bcod3.value.

As you can see, each of these columns has a name, but having tried...

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod" . $x . ".value SEPARATOR 0x1F) AS unit_code
```

... I got an error from the surrounding CONCAT_WS().

I tried...

```
IF(bcod" . $x . ".value = '', 'QQQ', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod" . $x . ".value SEPARATOR 0x1F))
```

... but that doesn't appear to do anything.

I tried...

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(bcod" . $x . ".value = 0, 'QQQ', bcod" . $x . ".value) SEPARATOR 0x1F)
```

.. and while it did grab the instances of bcod3.value, it also grabbed some of the instances of bcod1.value that have values which are not '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I think I do.  Sample data and desired results are worth 1000 words of explanation.

If the problem is that `NULL` or blank values are being ignored, then just do:

```
CONCAT_WS(0x1D,
          coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod1.value SEPARATOR 0x1F), ''),
          coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod2.value SEPARATOR 0x1F), ''),
          coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod3.value SEPARATOR 0x1F), ''),
          coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bcod4.value SEPARATOR 0x1F), '')
         ) AS clients_options
```

It is generally considered a benefit that `group_concat()` and `concat_ws()` ignore `NULL` values.  However, if you want to do something with them, just use `coalesce()`.

Comment: I'll reply again once I've finished running some examples.